creating specific flash memory area in STM32G0 microcontroller
I am trying to create a 2K flash memory region in which user defined const uint32_t will be stored.
The project is built in Keil uVision. The microcontroller has 64K of flash memory.
The idea is to allocate 2K of flash memory at the end of the total memory that is available.
I have edited the original uVision generated scatter (.sct) file to include an additional execute region of size 2K. I reduced the load region LR_IROM1 from 64K down to 62K.
  
  ER_IROM1 0x08000000 0x0000F800  {  ; main execution region, reduced by 2KB
   *.o (RESET, +First)
   *(InRoot$$Sections)
   .ANY (+RO)
   .ANY (+XO)
  }
  
  ER_PARAMETER_FLASH 0x0800F800 0x00000800  {  ; 2KB region for parameters
   *(.parameter_section)
   .ANY (+RO)
  }

  RW_IRAM1 0x20000000 0x00009000  {  ; RW data
   .ANY (+RW +ZI)
  }
}

In the main program, the flash data is generated with some random uint32_t constants as follows:
__attribute__((section(".parameter_section"))) const uint32_t my_flash_data[4] = {0xDEADBEEF, 0xCAFEBABE, 0xBAADF00D, 0xFACEB00C};

To ensure that this data is referenced, in the main loop the following is put:
uint32_t value = my_flash_data[0];  

The build process does not return any errors. However, looking at the .map file Image Symbol Table, it appears that this data is written just after the main program data and it happens to be the last entry:
    Execution Region ER_PARAMETER_FLASH (Exec base: 0x0800f800, Load base: 0x08001aa0, Size: 0x00000010, Max: 0x00000800, ABSOLUTE)

    Exec Addr    Load Addr    Size         Type   Attr      Idx    E Section Name        Object

    0x0800f800   0x08001aa0   0x00000010   Data   RO           86    .parameter_section  main.o

However the load address is not the same as the execution address. This does however make sense, since the actual data is stored at that memory address, but that is not what I wanted to achieve.
The my_flash_data address should have been 0x0800f800.
Is there a way to fix this? Could there be another load region created for this memory .sct file instead? If so, what are the changes that need to be implemented?
I have tried to change the load region from 0x08000000 0x0000F800 to 0x08000000 0x00010000, but it seems that it has no effect on it.

Just a guess but your first section has a .ANY (+RO) clause. If they're evaluated in order, maybe that's scooping up your my_flash_data data.
